# How change the "batch size" of a AWS Lambda MSK Event source

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-msk

I created an MSK Cluster and a Lambda Function I want to be triggered when there are new events on the events on the MSK Cluster.

I created the event source, and it says:

```
Batch size: 100
```

I want a lower Batch size, but I cannot find any way to change it. Not via CLI and not via the AWS web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [create-event-source-mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-event-source-mapping.html) or [update-event-source-mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-event-source-mapping.html) API. Both have a batch size option where you can set that up:

--batch-size (integer)

The maximum number of items to retrieve in a single batch.
Amazon Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka - Default 100. Max 10,000.

Comment: does this mean that lambda will trigger the function only when it can fetch `batch_size` messages ?

Comment: any way to add consumer timeouts ?